# Devtools install_git error

Tags: r, git, apache, github, devtools

I have a doubt about “install_git” function of “devtools” package

I’m now a little bit blocked, so if you could help me..

My situation is:

- Centos 6.5 with Apache web server and a local CRAN Mirror in
  /var/www/html/Rrepositories/CRAN
- RStudio Server and R 3.2.3 in another Linux machine for developing.
- For R developers we have thought to use “git” and “devtools” for sharing and version code. Enterprise have a local corporative Git
  with LDAP authentication.
- So if they want a CRAN package, they go to mirror and if they want private repositories, they go to corporative local Git.

So I have made the next proves:

- Git clone of hadley/stringr package (for example) and put it into
  /var/www/html/stringr
- Protect this folder with user and password (with an LDAP local in my host for testing)
- Git clone of /var/www/html/stringr from another machine of my network and all OK.
- Access RStudio and create new project from git, so I have typed http://user@192.168.17.148/stringr/.git , it has question me the
  password and all OK.
- And the test with more problems is to make an “install_git(“http://user:password@192.168.17.148/stringr/.git”)”. I
  always get this error:

> Error in git2r::clone(x$url, bundle, progress = FALSE) :    Error in
>   'git2r_clone': Invalid Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

I think that I have misconfigured the Apache for serving git content. But I don’t know why. I also want to know if with "install_git" function is possible to hide the password (some file like .wgetrc or .netrc)

Could you help me please? I would appreciate…

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Apache to use a cgi script to serve the git repository, as shown here

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP

Comment: Ok. I will try it. But, if I can make "git clone http://user@192.168.17.148/stringr/.git" satisfactory, does it mean that Apache is serving well the git repository? Or not?